# A consequence of Ubiety

Tags: wordplay, poetry

Here's a poem/riddle I wrote called "A consequence of ubiety"
I'll post the second half which is the answer in poem form a few days from now.

```
What has a country, but not a crown.
Excluding an impairment of sight,
it has a place it looked up, but never down.

When it gets lost, it need not be found.
Because it has left but not right, 
there's a place to which it is bound.
```

What is it?

Comment: That’s a new word I learned today!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer:

> **A traveler**
>
> *Though only the king may wear the crown,*
> *a traveler has a home country and town.*
> Here down and up have no connection since "look up" also means to "search for directions"
>
>  *A traveler is not like an item when lost*
>  *The journey continues with only some time as a cost.*
>   Left is a direction from which right is set apart. But "Has left" is also a past tense of depart.
>
>  An object when "bound" is considered immobile
>
> A traveler can be bound while inter-modal

Hopefully some of this wordplay wasn't too much of a stretch.

An explanation of the title:

> If you can only be in one place at a time, you must travel to get to somewhere else.

Comment: I don't really like this answer. The British Queen is one of these (probably more so than anyone else). The second line is unexplained. Many people who get lost do need to be found. And we cannot say that these have "no right" in any sense of the word.

Comment: Yes, royalty travels, yes lost people need to be found. But there are are travelers that meet all these criteria. The answer was "A traveler" not "All travelers"

I will agree that some of this wordplay may have been a stretch though. I guess it made more sense to me than most people since I wrote it.

Comment: "I guess it made more sense to me than most people since I wrote it." -- Usually not a good sign that something will lead to a good puzzle.

Comment: How was I supposed to know that unless I showed it to people?